# Swift: Animate NSLayoutConstraint doesn't work

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints, jquery-animate

I read many (same) questions and answers at stackoverflow.com about my problem (NSLayoutConstraint doesn't animate). All of the solutions said that the code has to be:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ZeppelinYPosition: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var Zeppelin: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    animateHighScoreLabel()
}

func animateHighScoreLabel() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {
        self.ZeppelinYPosition.constant = 100
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()    //some said that this could written before the animation but it doesn't work too
    }
}
```

But no animation happened. The view only appears at the target point (in my case 100) and that's it. Someone could tell me why this is so?
Many thanks.

EDIT: What I tried too but doesn't work is that I removed the constraint with

```
view.removeConstraint(ZeppelinYPosition)
```

and then tried to change Zeppelin.frame.origin.y but the view just freeze at Point(0,0). Any suggestions?

Comment: How about removing `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`? I don't think you need that.

Comment: Could you explain why I don‘t need that?

Comment: I removed self.view.layoutIfNeeded() but it still doesn't work. Any other suggestions?